# How to solve “ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)”

Tags: python, machine-learning

This is the code and after run it will generate ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

```
  ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-26-4db7f285beec> in <cell line: 9>()
  7 #loading the file that contains all data
  8 #mapping them into descriptions dictionary img to 5 captions
  ----> 9 descriptions = all_img_captions(filename)
 10 print("Length of descriptions =" , len(descriptions))
 11 

 <ipython-input-8-c532df34dea5> in all_img_captions(filename)
 13     descriptions ={}
 14     for caption in captions[:-1]:
 ---> 15         img, caption = caption.split('\t')
 16         if img[:-2] not in descriptions:
 17             descriptions[img[:-2]] = [ caption ]
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

How do I solve this error?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: What line is the error on?